# SQL Server Group by clause issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a query

```
select id, sum(col1), col2, col3, ......... col10 
from table
```

If I run this without group by clause it gives an error

> Column 'dbo.table.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If i use group by clause

```
select id, sum(col1), col2, col3, ......... col10 
from table 
group by col4
```

again the same error

> Column 'dbo.table.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Until i haven't  specified all those columns that hasn't implemented any aggregate function on it.

Now i cant apply an aggregate function on my all columns or i have to explicitly include all of my columns in group by clause

Comment: That is the way aggregates work, you have to group by the non aggregated columns. I am not seeing a question in your question though?

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.
As for your first query though, you could get the SUM without grouping the rows, if you use an analytic function:

```
select id,
       sum(col1) over () as sum_col1, -- here you have the analytic function
       col2,
       col3,
       ......... col10 
  from table
```

This way, you still get all the rows in the table, but on each row you will have the sum of col1.

You could also have the sum over col4 (as for your second query), if you add a partition by clause to the analytic function:

```
select id,
       sum(col1) over (partition by col4) as sum_col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       ......... col10 
  from table
```

You will still get the same number of rows, but the sum will be grouped by col4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to get all Columns

```
Select id, col2,col3, ......... col10,sumcol1
From table t1 inner join 
(
select sum(col1) as sumcol1, col4 as coln4 from table 
group by col4
) t2
on
t1.col4 =t2.coln4
```